# Копирование элементов на сайте

Tags: javascript, html, css

Привет как исправить вот такую проблему, есть меню, но если зажать на вкладку и пытаться перетащить, получается вот такое

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
user-select: none;
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandr barakin очевидно же, что речь о css коде, который нужно вставить в стиль проблемного элемента